# FFMPEG makes my server crash

Tags: php, crash, ffmpeg, cpu

I have a youtube mp3 converter site, and to do this I am using FFMPEG.

The problem is that the FFMPEG is using 100% CPU when there are some converting process together, so users can't access my site until the processes are finished.

How can I limit the CPU usage of FFMPEG? Is there another solution to solve my problem?

Comment: Accept some of your questions...

Comment: @Lawrence, I'm not sure that will solve the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running windows? or Linux? your question was very vague.

I suggest adding a process queue to make sure that only one youtube video is converting at a time. this can be done with simple unix timestamps (for timeout) and a database.

Answer (score -1):

You could make it execute with a lower process scheduling priority:

```
 exec("nice nice ffmpeg -i video.mp4 output.mp3");
```

http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/nice.1.php

Comment: Yes, you must try that out yourself.

Comment: No! Invoking nice twice creates a redundant 2nd process (which will still steal scheuling slots). In the absence of args, nice increases the scheduling niceness by a factor of 10. If you want to double that, use 'nice -20'